# Getting below error in remix editor

Tags: remix

Just starting with this code -

pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract test {
    uint public manager;

}

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which compiler version you have selected from the drop down on remix?
Please select 0.4.17 compiler and check what happens.

Comment: Yup, its solved. Selected 0.4.17+commit.bdeb9e52.Emscripten.clang compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Do not worry. Select the 0.4.25 (or so) compiler in the “run” tab. It is a consequence of a bad compiler loading.